# I want hide url

Tags: javascript

I want hide URL in the address bar Using Code JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slug = document.location.pathname;
{
var ncr = "" ;

window.location.replace(ncr);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure why you would want to hide the path name but you could modify your `.htaccess` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can override location in address bar by pushing another state in history. But remember that it will append to browse-history. More info you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)

```
history.pushState({}, null, "overrided.html");
```

Or with replacing state:

```
history.replaceState({}, null, "overrided.html");
```

Comment: This would do work well for what the OP is asking but using this method will is bad for bookmarking/sharing the url as it will bookmark the new url but if you try visit that url the chances are it will return 404 or the incorrect page. I just wanted to place this comment so the OP and others who choose to use this method are aware of those problems it can cause.

Comment: Sure. But as I understood - url must be not accessible. In that case it will help

Comment: I understand your point Alex but using a client-side language to hide it isn't going to make is secure. Browser settings, disable javascript and you'll have the original URL meaning the client now knows of the true URL. This isn't an issue with your solution. This is more towards the use of this and if the OP is aware that it will not make the original path securely hidden or untraceable. Like I said, for what the OP is asking for this will work. I just wanted to point out the disadvantages of using javascript to do this.

Comment: Also the true URL must be given otherwise how can the client get on that page for the javascript to spoof/change the pathname...

Comment: Completely agree with you. But if it is just some sample or js-application everything is fine. If it's not - .htaccess rules will be best choice

Answer (score -1):

With this can get the context

```
var contexto = '/' + window.location.pathname.split("/")[1];
```